# perforce + reviewboard output from p4 diff2 unable to upload to review board

Tags: perforce, review-board

I got diff file generated using following command

```
p4 diff2 -duw //depot/mainbrach... //depot/proj_branch... |  grep -v "identical" > changes.diff
```

i try to create review request with this diff file using rbt tool

```
rbt post --diff-filename=changes.diff --server=http://XXX
```

I get following error

```
 ERROR: Error uploading diff
 The generated diff file was empty. This usually means no files were modified in this change.Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.
```

I also found that the diff format is different from what reviewboard accepts (compared with old review diff files)

Some places in the net it was mentioned that post-review or external tool can be used to correct the same. But could not find exact solution.
Please help me
Thanks in Advance